# Suppress footnote number in text area

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, footnotes, footer

I have references from several captions to the same footnote. This footnote is not referenced from text, only from captions. I've found the following approach working great, except that the footnote number also appears in the text area. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fleqn]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{ima/myFirstPic}
\dots
\vspace*{0.1cm}
\caption[myFirstCaption]{myFirstCaption \footref{myFootnote}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{ima/mySecondPic}
\dots
\vspace*{0.1cm}
\caption[mySecondCaption]{mySecondCaption \footref{myFootnote}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\footnote{\label{myFootnote} myFootnoteText}
\end{document}
```

I tried `{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{{\label{myFootnote} myFootnoteText}}}` but this suppresses also the number in the footnote area (at the bottom of the page) which must be kept visible. So the question is: How do I suppress only the footnote number that appears in the text area?

Comment: Why not using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`? However, you have to take care to print the footnote on the correct page with such constructs, because floats can always float. Note also, that you should not use `center` environment inside a float but `\centering` command, because environment `center` adds additional (unwanted) vertical space.

Comment: I experimented a lot with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, it did not work. The issue always was that the reference numbering is off. Do you have a working example of your idea with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`?

Comment: Already shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do such a dangerous game, you can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption[myFirstCaption]{myFirstCaption\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption[mySecondCaption]{mySecondCaption\footref{myFootnote}}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{\label{myFootnote}Note, this is dangrous, because the figures
  could float to the next page or even this footnote could be on the next page
  after changing something in the document!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See “[Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)” for more information about using `\centering` instead of `center` environment.

Comment: I see, so the combination of `\footnotemark` for the first caption and then `\footref` for the following captions avoids the chaos with the numbering. That's tricky, thanks!